# Why is this an example of n choose k? Confusion about combination

Tags: combinatorics

I am learning about combinations & I am not understanding how one example of nCk applies, since it is conceptually a bit different from example problems.

I have come to understand nCk as the amount of different combinations of k in set n. To me, this means choosing 5 cards for a unique hand out of 52, or the amount of combinations in a Champion's league round (4C2), or how to pick a set of 3 balls from 10 different colored balls (10C3).

However, in a video I am learning from (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rzac520CESc&index=30&list=UUSIi1EWpZ2TOt5gm_Fy1mXw), the instructor throws me for a loop when he uses scrabble tiles to make unique "words". He uses 3 S's and 7 F's and says a unique word is, for example, SFFSSFFFFF

He says this is an example of 10C3 but it is not immediately obvious to me because here it appears that order matters, and most importantly he isn't picking out three tiles out of ten tiles! Instead, it is now how the ten tiles are arranged. I wish I could explain myself better.

Comment: A simple explanation: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: thank you for responding. The examples are about the same as the ones I've encountered before, and do not cause me difficulty like the scrabble tiles example. Can you explain why the scrabble tiles is a valid example?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a string consisting of $3$ $S$’s and $7$ $F$’s: once you know which $3$ of the $10$ positions in the string are occupied by $S$’s, you know the whole string, because the other $7$ positions *must* contain $F$’s. If I show you $\cdot SS\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot S\cdot \cdot $, for instance, with the second, third, and eighth slots filled with $S$’s, you know that the string is $FSSFFFFFSFF$. This means that you can count the strings of this type by counting the number of different possible sets of $3$ positions for the $S$’s. Since there are $10$ positions altogether, there are $\binom{10}3$ (or $10C3$, if you prefer) sets of $3$ positions, and therefore $\binom{10}3$ different ways to place the $3$ $S$’s in the string. And as we just saw, that means that there are $\binom{10}3$ such strings.

Comment: Holy! I can't believe I didn't realize that. I thought it was conceptually like picking tiles and trying to figure out whether it was S or F, but really it's picking places for the S tiles. You explained this perfectly.

Comment: @foursuits: Glad it helped!